# Aggrid update/delete row and save to DataFrame in local folder

Tags: python, ag-grid, streamlit

I'me new on this forum, and sorry If I make some mistakes.

I have one question and It's about using Python, Streamlit and Aggrid.

In the previous days, I've tried to make some code to enable users to delete a row in Aggrid table, and to update that new state (state without deleted row) in a Dataframe saved in local folder. But, when I check an row, click delete button, row disapear in aggrid table, but after reload of streamlit page everything back in the state as before deleting row (deleted row is in table again). Also, the new state (state without deleted row) isn't saved in Dataframe in local folder. Can you pls check my code bellow to see what could be a problem?

Also, what is the syntax to enable user to update an row in aggrid table, and also to save it to Dataframe in local folder also?

Thx in advance,

best regards,

Adnan

```
import js as js
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
from st_aggrid import AgGrid, GridOptionsBuilder, JsCode, GridUpdateMode


file_dir = r'C:\Users\....\'
file_name = 'Wi_Fi_DB.xlsx'
filepath = f"{file_dir}/{file_name}"

def display_table(df: pd.DataFrame) -> AgGrid:
    sel_mode = st.selectbox('Choose row or rows', options=['single', 'multiple'])
    gb = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(df)
    gb.configure_selection('single', use_checkbox=True)
    gb.configure_selection(selection_mode=sel_mode, use_checkbox=True)

    string_to_delete = "\n\n function(e) { \n \
    let api = e.api; \n \
     let sel = api.getSelectedRows(); \n \
    api.applyTransaction({remove: sel}); \n \
        }; \n \n"

    cell_button_delete = JsCode('''
        class BtnCellRenderer {
            init(params) {
                console.log(params.api.getSelectedRows());
                this.params = params;
                this.eGui = document.createElement('div');
                this.eGui.innerHTML = `
                 <span>
                    <style>
                    .btn {
                      background-color: #F94721;
                      border: none;
                      color: white;
                      font-size: 10px;
                      font-weight: bold;
                      height: 2.5em;
                      width: 8em;
                      cursor: pointer;
                    }

                    .btn:hover {
                      background-color: #FB6747;
                    }
                    </style>
                    <button id='click-button'
                        class="btn"
                        >&#128465; Delete</button>
                 </span>
              `;
            }

            getGui() {
                return this.eGui;
            }

        };
        ''')

    gb.configure_column('Delete', headerTooltip='Click on Button to remove row',
                        editable=False, filter=False, onCellClicked=JsCode(string_to_delete),
                        cellRenderer=cell_button_delete,
                        autoHeight=True, suppressMovable='true')

    gb.configure_default_column(editable=True)
    gb.configure_selection(use_checkbox=True, selection_mode="multiple")
    grid_options = gb.build()
    grid_return = AgGrid(df, gridOptions=grid_options, allow_unsafe_jscode=True, theme="streamlit")

    with st.form(file_name):
        if JsCode(string_to_delete):
            df = grid_return["data"]
            df = df.append(df, ignore_index=True)
            df.to_excel(filepath, index=False)

df = pd.read_excel("Wi_Fi_DB.xlsx")
st.info("Select a row to remove it")
response = display_table(df)
df.to_excel("Wi_Fi_DB.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: You posted a code. Does it run on your computer?

Comment: yes, it does, but the problem is as I described. When I check an row, click delete button, row disapear in aggrid table, but after reload of streamlit page everything back in the state as before deleting row (deleted row is in table again). Also, the new state (state without deleted row) isn't saved in Dataframe in local folder.

Comment: Where do you get this code? What is Wi_Fi_DB.xlsx?

Comment: Hi. It's a code that I typed using some existing sollutins from github and web generaly. Wi_Fi_DB.xlsx is my local file - excell table which I use for this example ... It can be of course any table, just to make code to work deleting and saving in dataframe ...

Comment: If I run this code with sample excel file, I  got `StopIteration` exception.